# IE rendering: cursor detects (correctly) clickable element that is displayed (incorrectly) somewhere else

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a funny problem with internet explorer 8. My task is to make a web page work properly under Internet Explorer (unfortunately I'm not allowed to post link to this page here). The problem is: Some elements of the page are displayed in wrong places. They are misplaced on the page, but I can't click them in the place where they are displayed. I can click them if I click in the place they are supposed to be... Well, I bet it sounds confusing so here is a screen that may help:

[image: Misplaced button]

The button and the whole gray bar with "Liczba zmian: 5 [Pokaż]" is displayed in wrong position. It should be placed in the blank space where the cursor is. Now, if I try to click on the button that the red arrow is pointing on - nothing happens. However if I click on the blank place where the blue arrow is pointing to, the button is clicked and .click() function is executed.

It seems like if the cursor is seeing different (the correct) version of the website.

The whole page is stuffed with JQuery, JQuery-UI, JQuery.Weekdcalendar and many other jquery plugins. I have the following DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

"Obviously" everything works fine on Firefox and Chrome, I don't know about IE9 (I only have winXP).

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check in IE Developer Tools for the browser and document mode (you want IE 8 standards to make things like this more predictable).  I would try to force IE 8 standards mode using HTML 5 DOCTYPE

```
 <!doctype html>
```

and/or

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

in the head tag.  This is MSDN link is for IE 9 but would probably work for IE 8 as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Note if some things look weird when you change DOCTYPE--then your HTML/CSS probably has something messy/non-standard in that will eventually give you a problem on standards-based browsers (like if your customers upgrade to IE9).

Comment: Changing doctype doesn't change anything :( as well as changing modes in Developer Tools. It appears that it works fine in IE9.

Comment: Sorry, that's worked for me in the past.  I have also noticed another weird formatting issue in IE only, sometimes playing with display:relative/absolute with nearby elements has fixed it.  I will open developer tools, select the element and go to the layout tab. That might tell you if it is a calculated offset or something else.